# How to drop a temporary table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

A temporary table is created with a SELECT .. INTO statement

```
SELECT *
    INTO #MyTempTable
FROM ...
```

Under Databases, tempdb, Temporary Tables I see the temp table 
dbo.#MyTempTable____________________0000000016CA

Now I want to drop the table. I tried the following:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #MyTempTable
```

AND

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MyTempTable') IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN 
    DROP TABLE #MyTempTable 
END
```

Both didn't delete the table

The Select returns NULL:

```
SELECT OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MyTempTable')
```

Comment: `##MyTempTable` <> `#MyTempTable`.

Comment: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #MyTempTable doesn't work either

Comment: [Cannot replicate](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9ee04b47756373ef16d7be24c841f203)

Comment: @toms  Are you committing or not?

Comment: Yes, I executed and the result is "Command(s) completed successfully". But the table is still there

Comment: Do I lack the permissions and how to check?

Comment: Temp tables only exits for the duration of the script...Is that not happening?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the trick with the [OBJECT_ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/object-id-transact-sql).
But then make sure that the table that's checked for it's existance is the same as the one you drop.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MyTempTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN 
    DROP TABLE #MyTempTable;
END
```

Or simplified :

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MyTempTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #MyTempTable;
```

Comment: @Well, before the edit another table was dropped in the statement.  So I thought that could be it.  But do know that #temporary tables only exists within a session.  For example, if you open a window in SQL Server Managment Studio, then create a #temp table.  Then you can only select from that table within that query window, but not in another query window (since it's a different session).  And they get automatically dropped when the session is closed, f.e. when you close that query window.

Comment: Well, in the same session, after having created the table I run 
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MyTempTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN 
    DROP TABLE #MyTempTable;
END 
but the table is not dropped and OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MyTempTable', 'U') returns NULL what means that the table cannot be found although it exists

Comment: @toms Odd.  The syntax also works for me as expected. Even with the BEGIN & END.  Example snippet: `IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MyTempTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL  DROP TABLE #MyTempTable;

create table #MyTempTable (col int);
insert into #MyTempTable (col) values (1),(2),(3);

select * from #MyTempTable;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MyTempTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN 
    DROP TABLE #MyTempTable;
END

select * from #MyTempTable;`.   What version of SQL Server are you using (doubt that's it though)

Comment: @toms Just noticed something. You mention in your question `dbo.#MyTempTable____________________0000000016CA` But that looks like the naming for a normal table in the dbo schema?

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to the name of checked table and dropped table.. `#MyTempTable` vs `#lu_sensor_name_19`

This is working for me:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MyTempTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #MyTempTable;
```

if this does not work for you I think your problem is related to **scope and/or visibility** of your temp table.

temp tables exists only with the session where they were created,
I guess you are dropping a temp table that doesn't exists amymore, or a temp table in another session.

first you have to check if the session in which you make the `SELECT INTO` is still active when you want to drop the table.

if answer is yes, then check if you are dropping from the same session or from another one.

in the second case you can solve the problem using `##MyTempTable` instead of `#MyTempTable`

otherwise it means that something or someone else have already dropped it

Comment: I tried with #MyTempTable, just forgot to remove #lu_sensor_name_19

Comment: Then fix your question, @toms. At the moment you are saying you can't drop the table `#MyTempTable`, but in neither statement do you *try*. In one, you try to drop the object `##MyTempTable` instead, and in the other `#lu_sensor_name_19`. Of course people are going to think this is typographical if you haven't editted your question to fix them.

Comment: The table still exists, because when I execute SELECT *  INTO #MyTempTable FROM ... it says that the table already exists

Comment: maybe you are trying to drop it from another session, try using ##MyTempTable both when you create it and when you drop it